# how to add a constant value to a user input string

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im trying to send an alert `if`  the value of a user input in a UITextfield goes above 1.67 times the value entered.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField

float x = ([_continuityRingFinalR2.text floatValue]);
float y = (1.67);

if ([_continuityRingFinalR2.text > x * y] )//errors here {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"My message here" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];


    [alert show];
}
```

Im trying to say if _continuityRingCircuitR2.text is 1.67 times the users input show an alert.  I think im nearly there but just keep getting errors on `([_continuityRingFinalR2.text x * y] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is likely because "`continuityRingFinalR2`" is a label while the compiler is looking for some numeric value.

Try using this:

```
if ([[_continuityRingFinalR2.text floatValue] > x * y] ) {
```

(this answer assumes the value inside your label truly is a number)

Comment: Thank you thats sorted it, been stuck on that for ages, also fixed typo,  I should have been reading from _continuityRingFinalR1.text

Answer (score 1):

Are you dealing with two different inputs? 
From what's written, that will never be higher as you're taking the float value x, and seeing

```
if (x > x * y)
```

This will never be true since you set y = 1.67 ( or any other value greater than or equal to 1).

Did you mean to compare a different text field?

Also, as mentioned in the other answer, you also need to use the float value of the field instead of text.

Comment: yes that 1 of two errors I needed to to read from a very similar text field. Plus one for you thank you